# Stand-alone LaTeX -compiler for Windows i.e. without installation? Some USB -stick?

Tags: installing, windows, portability

My university [here](http://www.aalto.fi/en/) provides TeXnicCenter without compiler. I am unable to install the compiler due to permissions, I am forced to work in Windows environment during classes without traditional *ix tools such as `pdflatex`. I am now trying to find out a way to get my LaTeX -installations to something like USB-stick or other way without requiring permissions.

I don't have root -computer co cannot get any below methods working. So how can I get LaTeX compiler for Windows without installation due to limited permissions in my university?

**Perhaps related**

1. [TeX Installation on USB](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/tex-installation-on-usb)
2. [Standalone LaTeX editor/renderer for Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/standalone-latex-editor-renderer-for-windows)
3. [What is a good LaTeX compiler for Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31520/what-is-a-good-latex-compiler-for-windows)

Comment: Did you try the portable versions of TeX Live and MiKTeX?

Comment: It is very unusual to have TeXnicCenter installed without a working TeX distribution. Instead of rolling your own solution why don't you ask the IT department to install either MikTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @Alexander I did that already but it takes weeks or many days for them to respond (not speaking of resolving cases) and they are going weekend -holiday. They are not much motivated folks so the much faster way is to try solve on your own. They speak more why you cannot do things, not how you can do things, I don't much like that kind of attitude. I want to just get LaTex working.

Comment: Thanks, was just compiling an introductory course on LaTeX and was wondering if a portable version existed.

Comment: Isn't there som sort of online version? I seem to recall seeing something. That could probably work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would probably first try [Portable MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/portable). The website for distribution includes instructions on using it, and adds useful options to the context (right-click) menu for the drive you put it on. Configuring with a non-portable editor might be tricky, so I'd go with the TeXworks editor that is bundled with Portable MiKTeX.

If you cannot use the context menu for any reason, you should be fine staring TeXworks 'manually'. It's located in `miktex\bin` inside your portable installation.

Comment: ...do I need to download TeXworks installer in EXE or does it have some Portable version? +1 ...thank you for your input, taking time to test different choices in installation.

Comment: @hhh MiKTeX comes with TeXworks, so you should not have to install anything extra.

Comment: `"ShellExecutedEX failed; code 1260. This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator."` -- not starting well :( ... cannot find TeXorks in MiKTeX -extracted directory.

Comment: I only need Portable things when in the university Windows machines, no other place. So could I have them somehow only for the university?

Answer (score 0):

My friend Markus found a clever way in Debian -based distros such as Ubuntu or Debian itself. Now most people wanting something like this have a *ix laptop and in that necessary installations for LaTex. This tip will only work if you have already the installation of LaTex on your computer so basic idea: you use your own installation and you download the files from your school/uni server. You can also use just `$ scp -r username@school.com:workDir .` but the next way is more visually-pleasing.

[image]

> 1. Select `Places/Connect to Server` in the GUI
> 2. Put your credentials there, for example username as `hhh` and host as `kosh.aalto.fi`
> 3. input the password

now it may mount to the root so you need to find the dir, easy way is to login there with ssh like `` "eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add ~/.ssh/school; ssh hhh@kosh.aalto.fi" `` -- and now you should mount to your local -dir or do `$ cd ~/`. Then you get the path with `$pwd` -- it may be something like `/u/87/username/unix`, depending on your server -structure. Now in Debian, you can create Bookmark so next time you can click it in the menu, below an example.

[image]

After this, you can use your tools/editors in your own devices easily. Have fun!